Netflix conductor Timedout Task updates
My Question is related to Netflix conductor task update API.
Conductor task update API skips all task processing steps when it sees task already moved to terminal state.
In some scenarios, i see conductor client picked up the task and did not respond in time. In those cases i see task timeout but conductor client eventually completes its processing. Since conductor server already moved the task status to terminal state, it is not accepting any further updates on the task.
I see a problem where conductor client completes its processing but conductor server did not updates the task output. Here systems are not in consistent state. From workflow/conductor we identify client did not respond but not sure whether client completes it or not.
I wanted to know why conductor team decided to not accepting any updates for timeout tasks.
Also is it possible to allow conductor server to accepts the task update only for timeout tasks?
